# Is it possible to create dynamic keys in a object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

for example I ask the user to enter an input and he enters "key" and I save the value on a variable called INPUT.
Then I want to create an object with this like this.

var obj = {INPUT: "some other input"}; where INPUT = key

I know I can add more values but I need to know the key ahead of time in order to add it. Can I add a new key without knowing what it is?

Comment: You can do `var obj = {}; obj[Input] = "some other input";` where `var Input = "derp";` or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). Assuming `INPUT` is an actual variable, simply wrap it in `[]`.

```
var obj = {[INPUT]: "some other input"};
```

The *long* version of doing this would be to use bracket notation when adding your keys.

```
var obj = {};
obj[INPUT] = "some other input";
```